# Vert.x kafka consumers are pausing between fetching records

Tags: vert.x

I'm seeing that, even though the kafka topic has a lot of messages (millions) queued up, the vert.x consumer is only fetching 500 messages (the default fetch amount) and which it then passes on to the handler. But after the messages have been handled and committed the consumer just stops and waits for about 35 seconds until it fetches another batch of messages.

I would expect that the consumer would keep on fetching until it manages to catch up with the partition and then pause. How do I make it do so?

The consumer is setup with the following code:

```
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topic, result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                log.info("Kafka consumer successfully subscribed to topic {}", topic);
            } else {
                log.error("Kafka consumer failed to subscribe to topic {}", topic);
            }
            promise.handle(result);
        });
```

With the following configuration for the consumer:

```
group.id = somegroup
auto.offset.reset=latest
enable.auto.commit=false
max.poll.interval.ms=300000
max.poll.records=500
session.timeout.ms=10000
heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
```

I'm using vert.x 3.9.2 and Kafka is 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The delay was caused by a number of reasons. The most notorious reason was that the each individual message in the batched fetch was manually committed in a sequential fashion. Using autocommit speeded things up and I believe that committing the batch offset would speed things up even more.